# VideoView and .mp4 freezing

Tags: android, rtsp, android-videoview

Hi there everybody! I have some problem with VideoView when I try to play my .mp4 througn rtsp stream I got freezing pic on phone screen. At the same time sounds goes on fine, but video still freeze. For player I used standart code from api demos, mediaplayer and videoview work the same, it still freeing when play. Someone know the solution?

Here is info about the video from vlc player:
mpeg AAC Audio (mp4a) 44100 Gz
H264 - MPEG-4 AVC 480 x 320

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing this on an emulator, the emulator cannot play back video very well, unless you have an extremely fast development machine. I get the symptoms you describe playing back a *local* MP4 on a dual-core 2.5GHz notebook.

Comment: Nope, I trying on my HTC Hero. .3gp file streaming works fine, but .mp4 sound only. Of course I can recode video, but I think that .mp4 must playing too..